# Split lines using tags that appear multiple times in file

Tags: ruby

I have a file that has the contents as below:

```
this is test line 1 
this is testing purpose 
<public>
am inside of public
doing lot of stuffs and priting result here
</public>
<public>
am inside of another public
doing another set of stuffs and priting here
</public>
```

I want to split this file into three different sections:

1. The lines which are not inside any of the   section
2. The lines which are inside of first   section
3. The lines which are inside of second   section

I tried with `take_while` and `drop_while`,

```
File.open(filename).each_line.take_while do |l|
  !l.include?('</public>')
end.drop_while do |l|
  !l.include?('<public>')
end.drop(1))
```

but it extracts only the first `<public>`...`</public>` section.

I am looking for a better solution. Any suggestion would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
File.read(filename).split(/<\/?public>/)
                   .map(&:strip)
                   .reject(&:empty?) # [0..2] if the file has a tail
#⇒ [
#   [0] "this is test line 1 \nthis is testing purpose",
#   [1] "am inside of public\ndoing lot of stuffs and priting result here",
#   [2] "am inside of another public\ndoing another set of stuffs and priting here"
# ]
```

Comment: Thanks it worked! Can you explain how the map(&:strip) and reject(&:empty?) works in this scenario.

Comment: And also if some case the <public> section will come first and the normal content will go at last. then how can i confirm the which array element is belongs to the public section?

Comment: `split` shaves `"\n"` off and `reject` rejects empty strings (the one between closing and next opening tag.) If the preface might go in the end, the approach should be completely different. You might try to ask a new question, stating all the conditions precisely.