# ruby Split lines using selective tags that appear multiple times in file in any order

Tags: ruby

I have a file that has the contents as below:

```
this is test line 1 
this is testing purpose 
<public>
am inside of public
doing lot of stuffs and priting result here
</public>
<public>
am inside of another public
doing another set of stuffs and priting here
</public>
```

I want to split this file into three different sections:

1. The lines which are not inside any of the   section
2. The lines which are inside of first   section
3. The lines which are inside of second   section

I tried with `take_while` and `drop_while`,

```
File.open(filename).each_line.take_while do |l|
  !l.include?('</public>')
end.drop_while do |l|
  !l.include?('<public>')
end.drop(1))
```

but it extracts only the first `<public>`...`</public>` section.

In some situation the order might change, like the public section will come first and the remaining content will come at last or middle. If the content order is same as above template then I can follow the below mothod

```
File.read(filename).split(/<\/?public>/)
                   .map(&:strip)
                   .reject(&:empty?)
```

which I got answer from [Split lines using tags that appear multiple times in file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44389768/split-lines-using-tags-that-appear-multiple-times-in-file).

But looking some generic method where I can handle the data if the order is in anyway.

I am looking for a better solution. Any suggestion would be appreciated.

Comment: they make html parsers that might be more useful to you like `nokogiri`.

Comment: This is an "[XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/153968)". You're asking how to accomplish something after deciding how to do it, but it's the wrong way to go. This is a problem for a parser, like Nokogiri.

Comment: Whenever you give an example please show your desired result as a (valid) Ruby object. Might there be lines other than tags after your last `</public>`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Ruby's [flip-flop operator](http://nithinbekal.com/posts/ruby-flip-flop/) here.

**Code**

```
def dissect(str)
  arr = str.lines.map(&:strip)
  grp, ungrp = [], []
  arr.each { |line| line=='<public>'..line=='</public>' ? (grp << line) : ungrp << line }
  [grp.slice_when { |s,t| s == '</public>' && t == '<public>' }.
       map { |a| a[1..-2] },
   ungrp]
end
```

The last statement of the method, which constructs the array returned by the method, could be replaced with the following.

```
b = grp.count('<public>').times.with_object([]) do |_,a|
  ndx = grp.index('</public>')
  a << grp[1..ndx-1]
  grp = grp[ndx+1..-1] if ndx < grp.size-1
end
[b, ungrp]
```

**Example**

```
str =<<-EOS
this is test line 1 
this is testing purpose 
<public>
am inside of public
doing lot of stuffs and printing result here
</public>
let's stick another line here
<public>
am inside of another public
doing another set of stuffs and printing here
</public>
and another line here
EOS
```

```
grouped, ungrouped = dissect(str)
  #=> [
  #     [ ["am inside of public",
  #        "doing lot of stuffs and printing result here"],
  #       ["am inside of another public",
  #        "doing another set of stuffs and printing here"]
  #     ],
  #     [
  #       "this is test line 1",
  #       "this is testing purpose",
  #       "let's stick another line here",
  #       "and another line here"]
  #     ]
  #   ]
grouped
  #=> [ ["am inside of public",
  #      "doing lot of stuffs and printing result here"],
  #     ["am inside of another public",
  #      "doing another set of stuffs and printing here"]
  #   ]
ungrouped
  #=> ["this is test line 1",
  #    "this is testing purpose",
  #    "let's stick another line here",
  #    "and another line here"]
```

**Explanation**

For the example above the steps are as follows.

```
arr = str.lines.map(&:strip)
  #=> ["this is test line 1", "this is testing purpose", "<public>",
  #    "am inside of public", "doing lot of stuffs and printing result here",
  #    "</public>", "let's stick another line here", "<public>",
  #    "am inside of another public", "doing another set of stuffs and printing here",
  #    "</public>", "and another line here"]

ungrp, grp = [], []
arr.each { |line| line=='<public>'..line=='</public>' ? (grp << line) : ungrp << line }
```

The flip-flop returns `false` until `line=='<public>'` is `true`. It then returns `true` and continues to return `true` until *after* `line=='</public>'` is `true`. It then returns `false` until it once again encounters a line for which `line=='<public>'` is `true`, and so on.

```
ungrp
  #=> <returns the value of 'ungrouped' in the example>
grp
  #=> ["<public>",
  #    "am inside of public",
  #    "doing lot of stuffs and printing result here",
  #    "</public>",
  #    "<public>",
  #    "am inside of another public",
  #    "doing another set of stuffs and printing here",
  #    "</public>"]
enum = grp.slice_when { |s,t| s == '</public>' && t == '<public>' }
  #=> #<Enumerator: #<Enumerator::Generator:0x00000
```

See [Enumerable#slice_when](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-slice_when), which made its debut in Ruby v2.2.

We can see the elements that will be generated by this enumerator by converting it to an array.

```
enum.to_a
  #=> [["<public>", "am inside of public",
  #     "doing lot of stuffs and printing result here", "</public>"],
  #    ["<public>", "am inside of another public",
  #     "doing another set of stuffs and printing here", "</public>"]]
```

Lastly,

```
enum.map { |a| a[1..-2] }
  #=> <returns the array 'grouped' in the example>
```

Comment: It worked with Ruby V2.2. Is there any other method available on Ruby v1.9.3 instead if slice_when to make it work?

Comment: I provided an alternative to the use of `slice_when` that should work will all versions of Ruby. If you use Rails you really need to learn Nokigiri. As you can see from @theTinMan's answer it's much better suited to this type of problem than a pure Ruby solution. Why didn't I give a Nokigiri answer? I don't know it (or Rails), and even if I did, Sn-man had already posted his answer.

Answer (score 1):

Consider this:

```
require 'nokogiri'

doc = Nokogiri::XML(<<EOT)
<root>
this is test line 1 
<public>
am inside of public
</public>
<public>
am inside of another public
</public>
</root>
EOT

text_inside_public_tags = doc.search('public').map(&:text)
# => ["\n" +
#    "am inside of public\n", "\n" +
#    "am inside of another public\n"]

doc.search('public').each(&:remove)

text_outside_public_tags = doc.at('root').text
# => "\n" +
#    "this is test line 1 \n" +
#    "\n" +
#    "\n"
```